# OpenAL iPhone: unable to play any sound

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, openal

I'm trying to get to play a simple sound file through OpenAL by referring [this tutorial](http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/comment-page-1/#comment-379):

I've created a monolithic code from it to test initially, but cant get the sound to play. I've been trying a lot of stuff but I can't get the sound to play. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
ALCdevice* device;
device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);

ALCcontext* context;
alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
alcMakeContextCurrent(context);

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mg" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL* pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AudioFileID audioID;
OSStatus audioStatus = AudioFileOpenURL((CFURLRef)pathURL, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &audioID);


UInt32 fileSize = 0;
UInt64 outDataSize;
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(UInt64);
OSStatus res = AudioFileGetProperty(audioID, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &propSize, &outDataSize);
fileSize = (UInt32)outDataSize;

unsigned char* outData = malloc(fileSize);
OSStatus res2 = AudioFileReadBytes(audioID, false, 0, &fileSize, outData);

AudioFileClose(audioID);

ALuint bufferID;
alGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
alBufferData(bufferID, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, outData, fileSize, 44100);

ALuint sourceID = 2;
alGenSources(1, &sourceID);
alSourcei(sourceID, AL_BUFFER, bufferID);
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
alSourcei(sourceID, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
free(outData);
outData = NULL;

alSourcePlay(sourceID);
```

Comment: I don't know much about openAL, but have you tried the AVAudioPlayer?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067 it may be user to use

Comment: Yes, i've tried AVAudioPlayer, but i've read its fine only if latency can be tolerated. That is, its not advised for playing sound effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out!
I have been using:

```
alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
```

instead of:

```
context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
```

The alGetError() helped in pointing this out.

Comment: you need to mark your own answer as the correct answer, otherwise it still comes up as an unanswered question